# Enabling and disabling port 443 for web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, iis-express

I have two ASP.NET applications which i'm migrating to OIDC. Also i created OIDC request mentioning to accept request for 443. Now that i have two applications running on port 443 i started getting this error.

[image]

How can i alter between applications by running on same port by disabling the other application without having to change the port#

Comment: the port can be used once at a time. Two applications can not use the same port.

Comment: i realize that looking by looking at the error. My question is how do i enable or disable the port# based on which app i'm currently working on.

Comment: You can configure in project properties to use 443 port in both the projects. It should work as long as you run one project at a time.

Comment: Yes i'm running one application at a time. But still somehow it showing me that error. I restarted my machine and tried as well. Do you know if i should kill/restart some process in task manager?

Comment: Instead of using IIS Express, host everything on IIS and then use SNI to bind those two HTTPS web apps on port 443 with different host names.

Comment: Based on your description, I found a way to see what process is using port 443.
Open CMD with run as administrator. And run netstat -ao | find /i "443".
Then you can then use the PID to find the process in task manager. Or use the command of "taskkill /PID <PID> /F" in CMD. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by stopping all the other apps on IIS that were ported on port# 443.

Comment: It's great that you found the solution. Could you share the steps of the solution? You can mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community member in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.